# Python se congela en un While Loop

Tags: python

Mediante un while loop lanzo un comando en cmd (windows), que se repite cada 60 segundos. En un determinado momento, el script que lanzé por cmd se congela y el loop queda trabado. ¿De que manera el script de python puede interrumpir y arrancar automáticamente el while sin que importe el estado del cmd?

Este sería el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
# Import time for sleep
import datetime
import time
import os

count = 0

while(True):

    os.system('...')

    # Fecha
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    fecha = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    
    print(fecha + " / Descarga: %d" % (count + 1))
    count += 1

    time.sleep(60)
```

---

## ACTUALIZACIÓN N1

El problema ahora son los argumentos. Primero paso el código del .py y luego una captura de los errores que causa el cmd.

```
import datetime
import subprocess
import time

d_token = "ewifjweof87ew98f7we"
d_channel = "9809808"
d_date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") ## dd/mm/yyyy format
d_format = "PlainText"
cmd = ["DiscordChatExporter.Cli.exe", "-t", d_token, "-c", d_channel, "-o", "logs-gocrypto.txt", "--datefrom", d_date, "-f", d_format]

timeout = 60

count = 0
while True:
    t0 = time.perf_counter()
    try:
        subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, timeout=timeout, shell=True)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        fecha = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
        print("{} / Descarga: {}".format(fecha, count + 1))    
        count += 1

    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print("[ERROR] Proceso terminado tras timeout")

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("[ERROR] El proceso no termino correctamente")

    finally:
        t_restante = timeout - (time.perf_counter() - t0)
        if t_restante > 0:
            time.sleep(t_restante)
```

El error en CMD
[image: Error en CMD]

Comment: Te recomiendo usar subprocess en vez de os.system, te va a dar mucho más control, incluido la eventual terminación del proceso. ¿Lo que quieres es matar el proceso a los 60 segundos sin importar en que estado esté (si no ha terminado por cualquier causa)? ¿Que versión de Python usas?

Comment: Otra cosa, ¿quieres lanzar cada  60 segundos siempre o en caso de que el proceso termine antes de ese tiempo realizar otra llamada inmediatamente?

Comment: Si, quiero matar el proceso a los 60 segundos sin importar el estado. Uso Python 3.6. 
Y respondiendo a tu último comentario, siempre debe ser cada 60 segundos..

Comment: probaste con `import win32com.client` y crear un task en el scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `os.system` llama al proceso y se **queda esperando a que este termine**, lo que detiene tu código en este punto indefinidamente, sin poder temporizar ni matar el proceso.

Primero de todo, debes usar el módulo [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.TimeoutExpired) en vez de `os.system`, la cual se considera en la práctica "*deprecated*" en versiones modernas de Python y para tus propósitos es demasiado rudimentaria. `subprocess` te va a permitir mucho más control sobre el proceso; comunicación directa con el proceso durante su ejecución (paso de comandos y recepción de respuestas), redirección de *dtdin*, *stdout* y *stderr*, envío de señales de terminación, chequeo del estado del proceso y de su salida, timeouts, etc.

Dicho esto, y suponiendo que usas Python 3, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Si quieres que el script lance el proceso, espere a su terminación e **inmediatamente lance otro cuando termine**, matando el anterior si este no  ha terminado pasados 60 segundos, puedes usar `subprocess.run` o `subproces.check_call` con un `timeout`:

  ```
  import datetime
  import subprocess

  cmd = "tu_comando"
  timeout = 60

  count = 0
  while True:
      try:
          subprocess.run(cmd, timeout=timeout, check=True)
          now = datetime.datetime.now()
          fecha = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
          print("{} / Descarga: {}".format(fecha, count + 1))    
          count += 1

      except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
          print("[ERROR] Proceso terminado tras timeout")

      except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
          print("[ERROR] El proceso no termino correctamente")
  ```
- Si quieres lanzar el proceso cada 60 segundos siempre, forzando su terminación si aún sigue vivo tras ese tiempo, puedes usar también `subprocess.run` pero con una pequeña modificación para esperar el tiempo restante si el proceso termina antes de los 60 segundos:

  ```
  import datetime
  import subprocess
  import time

  cmd = "tu_proceso"
  timeout = 60

  count = 0
  while True:
      t0 = time.perf_counter()
      try:
          subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, timeout=timeout)
          now = datetime.datetime.now()
          fecha = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
          print("{} / Descarga: {}".format(fecha, count + 1))    
          count += 1

      except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
          print("[ERROR] Proceso terminado tras timeout")

      except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
          print("[ERROR] El proceso no termino correctamente")

      finally:
          t_restante = timeout - (time.perf_counter() - t0)
          if t_restante > 0:
              time.sleep(t_restante)
  ```

Si tu comando es un buit-in de la propia terminal (como `mkdir`, `dir`, `copy`, etc) se necesita pasar el argumento `shell=True` a `subprocess.run`, para el resto de casos no es necesario ni recomendable (por ejemplo para ejecutar un archivo batch).

> **Nota:** si lo deseas puedes redireccionar stdout y stderr para obtener la salida estándar del proceso en el script Python.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. Pruebo el código pero me devuelve el siguiente error
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "discord-logs.py", line 12, in <module>
     p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, check=True)
 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'check'

Comment: @TomasReitmann , si tienes razón fue error mio al escribir el código copiando y pegando... :( De todas formas he simplificado la segunda opción usando también `subprocess.run`, ahora debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Excelente @FJSevilla, pero un detalle más quiero consultarle. Al cambiar el os.system, ahora la consola me da: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape ........ y eso es porque en la variable cmd debo usar slash invertido ( \ ), sino da error (en la aplicacion cmd, no en python). Y aqui se complejiza un poco mas el tema, ademas del path y el exe, le paso ciertos comandos específicos de la aplicación cli (C:\Users\app\app.exe -d 27/04/2018 -f PlainText). Espero que se entienda. Desde ya, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: @TomasReitmann usa un string "crudo": `cmd = r"C:\Users\app\app.exe -d 27/04/2018 -f PlainText"` para que no escape los caracteres, no obstante desde Python si que puedes usar `cmd = C:/Users/app/app.exe -d 27/04/2018 -f PlainText` o `cmd = C:\\Users\\app\\app.exe -d 27/04/2018 -f PlainText` sin problemas.

Comment: Si los argumentos son generados dinámicamente por el propio script Python puedes formatear la cadena o usar una lista `d_arg = "27/04/2018" ` \ `f_arg = "PlainText"` \ `cmd = [r"C:\Users\app\app.exe, "-d", d_arg, "-f",  f_arg]` (aunque en este caso, Windows y `shell=False`, la lista va a convertirse en cadena de todas formas durante la ejecución de `subprocess.run`)

Comment: Con esta última sugerencia nos acercamos. El problema es que usando "r" genera doble slash "\\" y al ejecturase la aplicación cli me da error. El resto de los parametros están bien. El problema son los slash invertidos entre python y la aplicación CLI.

Comment: @TomasReitmann no termino de entender la causa verdadera del error, la ruta no es un argumento para la aplicación CLI, algo se nos escapa... Puedes comprobarlo abriendo por ejemplo Notepad `subprocess.run(r"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe")` con lo que no hay ningún problema, incluso pasando como argumento la ruta de un archivo a abrir `subprocess.run([r"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe", r"C:\Users\Public\ejemplo.txt"])`.

Comment: ¿Con `shell=True` falla también? ¿La app CLI necesita ser ejecutada teniendo como directorio de trabajo el directorio donde está el script Python  o no?¿Si ejecutas el comando en CMD pero situándote primero en el directorio del script Python funciona? **¿O el error se debe al argumento -f que es en realidad una ruta?**

Comment: Muchas gracias por la velocidad en tus respuestas. Recientemente he probado mover el file .py en el directorio donde ejecuto el comando cmd y me aparece el mismo error, entonces queda descartado lo del doble slash. Con shell=True sigue igual. Creo que el problema se origina en las comas de los argumentos, es decir entre el .exe y -f. Probé directamente en Simbolo de sistema ejecutar el cmd usando comas y el error es el mismo con el script en python.

Comment: @TomasReitmann ¿Podríasañdir un ejemplo real que muestre como generas todo lo que  le pasas a `subproccess.run` y mostrar también el error que te genera, la forma en la que realizas la llamada directamente en CMD que funciona y la que no?  A ver si conseguimos dar con lo que pasa. Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/159607/edit) tu pregunta y añadir la información al final de esta.

Comment: hice un update en la pregunta.

Comment: ¿@TomasReitmann para el ejemplo que muestras como harías la llamada directamente en CMD para que funcione? Para la fecha de hoy '29/04/2018' por ejemplo. La verdad es que el error no es muy explícito, ayuda poco... :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76751/discussion-between-tomas-reitmann-and-fjsevilla).